Sprockets::Rails::Helper::AssetNotFound in Devise
Sprockets::Rails::Helper::AssetNotFound in Devise::Registrations#new
Showing /home/pawel8108/code/Pawel8108/countrol_app/app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb where line #10 raised:
The asset "pages/sign_up_page.css" is not present in the asset pipeline.
Extracted source (around line #10):
8  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
9
10 <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'pages/sign_up_page', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
11 <link
12   rel="stylesheet"
13   href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Krona One:wght@400&display=swap"
I get this alert when I open sign up on the app website and I don't know how to fix it or if someone can help me. I checked sign_up_page.scss, it is imported correctly, I also checked /countrol_app/app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb where line #10 wof, but I don't have a line like <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'pages/sign_up_page', media: 'all ', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %> I'm lost and I don't know how to fix it. Please help!!
